# how to know which tab start a new window in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, dns, browser-tabs

Recently, I encounter some weird new window that appear automatically.

So I wonder is there any way to find out a new window or tab is triggered by whom?

The page's url is "akakn.com", and result is a ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED page.

I can't find any info about it.

Maybe related to DNS hijack?

ps:
It shows in a little new window in pc and new tab in android.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting name not resolved because that is not a valid domain name.

1. Click the ants on a log (three dots)
2. Click Settings
3. Either search or navigate to `On Startup`

Now you can change the startup behavior.

4. Either search or navigate to `Show Home Button`

If you enable the home button you can customize what is shown on a new tab.

REFERENCE:
https://www.androidcentral.com/how-customize-your-chrome-startup-screen

Comment: My start up setting is open the New Tab page.
It seem not the same problem? I want to know how to find the initiator or origin of a page, like opened by user or opened by XXX.com... etc.
It shows in a little new window in pc and new tab in android.

Comment: So what is your new tab page set to? That's step 4. Show home button. Then you can change it.

Comment: the New Tab page open a blank new tab with google search and shortcuts. I don't use home button.

Comment: It's possible that I don't understand what the problem is you are describing.

Comment: It's ok, thank you for your reply.